# Send JSON variable from HTML to python(flask)

Tags: json, sqlite, flask

I have a flask website where the data comes from a sqlite3 database.
I have made a nested dropdown menu which is populated from a JSON array.

Now I have made a query that counts the number of idea's given the subject selected from the dropdown menu. But there is where I strand. How can I pass the value from the dropdown menu to my query in python?

Anyone an idea on how to solve this?

EDIT CODE:

This is my code i use to have my data from sqlite to JSON so i have a dropdown list which depends on the previous select.

```
var keyValueDataHealthRight = {{ keyValueProjectsHealthcare|tojson }};
                var keyValueDataEnterpriseRight = {{ keyValueProjectsEnterprise|tojson }};
                var keyValueDataEntetainmentRight = {{ keyValueProjectsEntertainment|tojson }};

                var stateObjectRight = {
                    "Entertainment": keyValueDataEntetainmentRight,
                    "Healthcare": keyValueDataHealthRight,
                    "Enterprise": keyValueDataEnterpriseRight

                };
                window.onload = function Right() {
                    var divisonSelR = document.getElementById("DivisionRightFilter"),
                        projectSelR = document.getElementById("ProjectRightFilter"),
                        subProjectSelR = document.getElementById("SubprojectRightFilter");
                    for (var divisionR in stateObjectRight) {
                        divisonSelR.options[divisonSelR.options.length] = new Option(divisionR, divisionR);
                    }
                    divisonSelR.onchange = function Right() {
                        projectSelR.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                        subProjectSelR.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done
                        for (var ProjectR in stateObjectRight[this.value]) {
                            projectSelR.options[projectSelR.options.length] = new Option(ProjectR, ProjectR);
                        }
                    };
                    divisonSelR.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
                    projectSelR.onchange = function Right() {
                        subProjectSelR.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done
                        var subProjectsR = stateObjectRight[divisonSelR.value][this.value];
                        for (var i = 0; i < subProjectsR.length; i++) {
                            subProjectSelR.options[subProjectSelR.options.length] = new Option(subProjectsR[i], subProjectsR[i]);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

My query code

```
SELECT  Ideastatus,COUNT(*) FROM Idea where project = '{{ variable }} ' GROUP BY ideaStatus ORDER BY IdeaStatus"
```

the problem I have is how to get the selected item and pass it to python so i can use it in my query

Comment: Can u show some code or example ?

Comment: yes sorry i edited with code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view which only gets POST method in your Flask App!

Something Like this:

```
@app.route('/get-query', methods=['POST'])
def getQuery(data):
    # Example Query
    query = 'SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE someColumn = {}'.format(data)
    # Do stuff with query and return it
    return do_stuff(query)
```

You can return a JSON function, You can return text, You can return HTML or even you can redirect user to some other view..

Even u can add `methods=['GET', 'POST']` to the view that you're using, then check if the `request.method` is `POST` and does it have `data`?
Something like this will work

```
@app.route('/some-route', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def someView(data=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if data:
            # Do something with data and return
            return do_stuff(data)
        return "You have to provide data!", 400
    return render_template('some_template.html')
```

Let me know if u didn't understand so I can explain more

Comment: I don't really get it in how I can send and retrieve the data from the select list  to python

Comment: There is a `value` attribute for each `option` tag u use, u set the value and then the value will get send, for example `<option value="server-will-retrive-me">Option Alias!</option>`, Also I can't understand whats the relation between sending a select list selected option to the python and ur question